# How to get the text value from a subitem by index in C#

Tags: c#, listview, indexing, indexof, subitem

I have managed to get the index from the very first item in the column in my listview, but from that same line I want to get the text value from the second Column by using the index number.

```
 // Gets the item from the listview
 var item = listview1.FindItemWithText(textbox4.Text);

if (item != null)
{
  // Gets the index number from that item
  var index = listview1.Items.IndexOf(item).ToString();
  string secondValue = listview1.Items(index).SubItems(1).Text);
  // secondVlaue should have the subitems txt value?

}
```

I really tried everything, but it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT:

There should be a method with `SubItem` cause it looks like this in visual:

```
 index      Name:                Information:
 0       Harry           Harry hasn't been online for 7 days
 1       Jason           jason hasn't been online for 5 days
 2       Sarah           Sarah hasn't been online for 2 days
 3       Jack            Online
```

What I know is that the index of Harry = 0 and the index of Jack = 3. So now with those index values I want to obtain the text value of the `Column` 'Information' that has the same index as the name `Column`.

This should be possible?

Comment: What if you say `listview1.Items(index + 1)`?

Comment: Is `index` a numerical value? You probably don't need `ToString()`.

Comment: I also suggest that you learn how to navigate the MSDN help documentation. It provides a lot of information about what methods are available for each class and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Here the index is assigned as a string .Make it as an integer then only `secondValue` will give any output .
var index = listview1.Items.IndexOf(item);

There is no method named `SubItems` in ListView class . If you want the next item means you need to plus 1 value to the index .

```
string secondValue = listview1.Items(index+1).ToString();
```